# How to run vs code from mac terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, visual-studio-code

I know I can open vs code from terminal by using command palette in vs code.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac

I have followed upper link's suggestion to install shell command. 
It did work for the first time.

But whenever I restart my computer or shut down the terminal and restart the terminal "code" command does not work.

it says

```
-bash: code: command not found
```

Is there any way I can fix this?
Or can I make an alias in .bash_profile to use "code" command to open vs code from terminal?

Comment: When I run `Install 'code' command...`, it puts a little Bash script in `/usr/local/bin/code`. Do you have that and does it work? It could be that you're using an older VS Code that's putting things in your `~/.bash_profile`, what version of VS Code do you have? If push comes to shove, you can of course put an alias in your `~/.bash_profile`: `alias code="/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code"`.

Comment: My version is 1.25.1 right now

Comment: whenever I do cmd+shift+p to install shell command, this message pops up:
Shell command 'code' successfully installed in PATH.
But if i restart my computer or shut down the terminal, the 'code' command doesn't work again

Comment: In a terminal where it works, what is the output of `which code`? Did you try the alias?

Comment: I don't understand the "-bash: code: command not found" part of your statement. Was that printed to the terminal? Is -bash your command prompt? How did you generate that message?

Comment: I was having the same problem and tried the method described in your link. It worked fine and is still working fine.

Comment: when i type "which code" 
there is no outcome